# JetBrains CLion IDE setup for ROS

Tags: catkin, clion, cmake

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I've downloaded it a couple of days ago, but I still have not figure out how to configure it correctly to work with ROS.

If I import a simple ROS project it gives me the following error, but I can compile (and run) it from the terminal:

```
Error: By not providing "Findcatkin.cmake" in CMAKE_MODULE_PATH this project has asked CMake to find a package configuration file provided by "catkin", but CMake did not find one.
Could not find a package configuration file provided by "catkin" with any of the following names:
  catkinConfig.cmake   catkin-config.cmake
Add the installation prefix of "catkin" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or set "catkin_DIR" to a directory containing one of the above files.  If "catkin" provides a separate development package or SDK, be sure it has been installed.
```

I'd like to know where to properly set these environmental variables and how can I get the equivalent of `catkin_make` from inside the IDE.

Thanks in advance!

---

### EDIT 29.11.2018

After more than three years, thanks to this post and to a couple of similar ones, JetBrains has published an official guide for CLion 2018.3 (which is fine also for previous versions).

You can find it here: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/clion/2018.3/ros-setup-tutorial.html

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/210534/jetbrains-clion-ide-setup-for-ros/) by [alextoind](https://answers.ros.org/users/20595/alextoind/) on ROS Answers with karma: 217 on 2015-06-03

Post score: 7

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2015-06-04**:
Also see [wiki.ros.org/IDEs](http://wiki.ros.org/IDEs).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It does not seem to find the catkin package in your environment variable.
How did you start CLion?
You should start it from a terminal which has all ROS setup bash scripts loaded. This ensures that all your environment variables are set correctly.
For me CLion works out of the box, when I start it in a terminal and I select a CMakelist for the project. I can build, run and debug without any extra configuration hassle.

---

Originally posted by [daenny](https://answers.ros.org/users/3203/daenny/) with karma: 376 on 2015-06-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 7

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [alextoind](https://answers.ros.org/users/20595/alextoind/) on 2015-06-04**:
Thank you very much, I didn't think about launching from terminal. It works like a charm now! Also, as pointed out by @gvdhoorn, in wiki.ros.org/IDEs there is the explaination for JetBrains PyCharm IDE which I haven't noticed while searching for 'CLion'.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2015-06-04**:
Might be nice to update the IDEs page to include a reference to your particular one. Would save future users some trouble.

**Comment by [mahi](https://answers.ros.org/users/22560/mahi/) on 2015-06-08**:
Following http://wiki.ros.org/IDEs  I edited clion *.desktop file as following so that I don't have to start it from command line every time.
Exec=bash -i -c "/bin/clion.sh" %f

**Comment by [bezcoder](https://answers.ros.org/users/22951/bezcoder/) on 2015-06-26**:
As suggested, by launching CLion from the terminal, that error doesn't come up anymore. Anyhow the build process doesn't work correctly as it outputs in some CLion system folder. Even if the catkin-generated CMakeCache looks fine, CLion uses a different BINARY_DIR for the project.

**Comment by [alextoind](https://answers.ros.org/users/20595/alextoind/) on 2015-06-27**:
It should be fine to source the proper `setup.bash`. For example if you are on linux try with: `source ~/.clion10/system/cmake/generated/<something>/<something>/Debug/devel/setup.bash`

**Comment by [bezcoder](https://answers.ros.org/users/22951/bezcoder/) on 2015-06-29**:
That way the building works in CLion but breaks catkin_make, so I don't consider that as a solution. CLion should just use the makefile in the appropriate directory (ros/build/$projectName) but it seems that it is failing at that.

**Comment by [gcc05](https://answers.ros.org/users/19929/gcc05/) on 2015-11-26**:
I agree with @bezcoder that there should be a way to make CLion generate the files in the catkin ws folders. Has anyone advanced with that? Or if there is any way to use the debugger with the catkin_make generated binaries?

**Comment by [alextoind](https://answers.ros.org/users/20595/alextoind/) on 2015-11-26**:
@grar05 actually you can use the debugger with binaries generated through `build <something>` from CLion, even if they are not those in the catkin workspace.

**Comment by [gcc05](https://answers.ros.org/users/19929/gcc05/) on 2015-11-27**:
Yes, I've been able to do that in some packages, but I have now a package that aborts when debugged from CLion (but not with the gdb command in the catkin_make binary). Also that I'd rather have the generated files in the workspace than compiling it twice, so debugging the catkin_made pkg would do.

**Comment by [Reuben John](https://answers.ros.org/users/24194/reuben-john/) on 2016-11-07**:
A [ROS plugin for CLion](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/206636449-Setting-CMake-Options-and-Build-Directory) requires one final Clion [issue](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/CPP-838) to be fixed. Voting for the fix will help speed things up!

**Comment by [alextoind](https://answers.ros.org/users/20595/alextoind/) on 2016-12-04**:
Thanks for the info! Actually with CLion 2016.3 it is now possible to set the cmake `build` directory, but I have not found how to separate the `devel` directory which is natively put inside the `build` one.